# Error trying build docker image customizable

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to use this predefined and customizable image:

https://hub.docker.com/r/webdevops/php-nginx/dockerfile

But I am getting an error:

```
Step 7/11 : COPY conf/ /opt/docker/
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder231406327/conf: no such file or directory
```

This is because I don't have any folder called `conf/` in my localhost and try to copy from there. Has someone used this kind of images?

In my app folder only I have the next content with the docker file in the root (https://github.com/banago/simple-php-website)

And I am running this command: `docker build -t php-test`

What do I have to do for this docker image to work?

Comment: Why are you rebuilding the image from the orignal dockerfile instead of simply using/extending it ? Make your own dockerfile starting with `FROM webdevops/php-nginx` inside your git project and simply copy your app in the resulting image, setting all the needed vars and customization files described in the [doc](https://dockerfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/DockerImages/dockerfiles/php-nginx.html)

Comment: Sorry @Zeitounator, I am new in this, then this dockerfile provided not is used for nothng? https://hub.docker.com/r/webdevops/php-nginx/dockerfile. According to the that you tell me, only I have to copy my files and define some vars/paremeters  specified in the documentation, but for do that I had to rebuld the image with my new dockerfile or what command I had to use?